# Java: How to monitor a plain socket connection (and forward results to the internal logger)

Tags: java, sockets, monitoring, inputstream, outputstream

I am spoiled by Netty but now comes day of reckoning...

I got a plain java.net.Socket here (to be more specific, a custom SocketPoolFactory where  Sockets are created along with a corresponding OutputStreamWriter and InputStreamWriter which wrap the socket's IO-Streams) and I need to monitor what is sent and received (in order to write this to the log file for debugging purposes).
Seems like I have a tough time to figure out where to hook in and intercept what is sent/received.

Can somebody help? What's the best to do this?
It is only for debugging (so does not need to be top notch efficient) (and if it helps somehow: I am working with Groovy).

Comment: If id does not have to be a pure-java solution, I'd go with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: To be clear, I don't want external tools for monitoring but in-application monitoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own FilterInputStream-derived class and interpose it in the stream stack attached to the socket,